# Warning: PowerShell detected that you might be using a screen reader and has disabled

Tags: python, digital-signature, webcam

Warning: PowerShell detected that you might be using a screen reader and has disabled PSReadLine for compatibility purposes. If you want to re-enable it, run 'Import-Module PSReadLine'.

PS C:\Users\ROHAN P SHRIRAME>

i want to see output of this code with showing sign conventions of hand